# Custom Relationship Segue

Tags: ios, segue, uistoryboard

As scenes in Storyboards can not be connected using `IBOutlets`, segues would be a great way.

While it's easy to create custom segues, there seems to be no way to create custom "Relationship Segues".

[image]

Is that so?
Only Apple can create such segues (`UITabBarController`'s `viewControllers`, `UINavigationController`'s `rootController`, etc.)?

Comment: You can create a custom segue that does what a relationship segue does, but you can't have it automatically execute when the source view controller is instantiated like Apple's relationship segues (however, you can call it in that controller's viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now we can actually do this!

[image]

Just create a custom `UIStoryboardSegue` subclass, then it will become available in Interface Builder.

The result is the same as creating a "Custom" segue and setting its class to your subclass.

An example from the [KWDrawerController](https://github.com/kawoou/KWDrawerController/blob/master/DrawerController/Segue/DrawerEmbedRightControllerSegue.swift) library:

```
public class DrawerEmbedRightControllerSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    final public override func perform() {
        if let sourceViewController = source as? DrawerController {
            sourceViewController.setViewController(destination, for: .right)
        } else {
            assertionFailure("SourceViewController must be DrawerController!")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're correct, you cannot create custom relationship segues.

Relationships segues are different from the other segues in that they are resolved at build time. When a UITabBarController is loaded from a storyboard, all of its constituent view controllers are already 'inside' of it in the same NIB that represents the scene with the tab bar controller.